# How to show and hide a ul if I am visiting the link included in the children

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `ul` list. If am visiting `http://exampel.com/1` then `.children` should be displayed. If am not then the `.children` should be hidden.

The same if am inside the `http://exampel.com/2` and the parent has class children so the class `.children` will be shown.

I did achieve the first goal by hiding the `.children` via CSS and then using this code to show it, but what am I missing to achieve the second goal?

```js
if ($('li').hasClass('current_page_item', 'page_item_has_children')) {
  $('.current_page_item .children').show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="page_item page_item_has_children current_page_item">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/1" aria-current="page">Jobba hos oss</a>
    <ul class="children" style="display: block;">
      <li class="page_item ">
        <a href="http://exampel.com/2">Anna-Lena jobbar hos oss</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item ">
        <a href="http://exampel.com/3">Luís jobbar hos oss</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item ">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/4">Lediga jobb</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/5">Cookie policy</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/6">För medarbetare</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/7">Information</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have control over the html to be able to set `current_page_item` then you could give all the items that should display together a unique data attribute, initially set everything to hidden, and on `$(document).ready()` show based on the value of the attribute.

```
<style>
.page_item{display:none}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var itemsToShow =  $(".current_page_item").data("group")
 $(".page_item[data-group='" + itemsToShow  + "']").show()
});
</script>

<ul>
  <li class="page_item current_page_item" data-group="1">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/1">Jobba hos oss</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item" data-group="1">
        <a href="http://exampel.com/2">Anna-Lena jobbar hos oss</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item" data-group="1">
        <a href="http://exampel.com/3">Luís jobbar hos oss</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item" data-group="2">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/4">Lediga jobb</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item" data-group="3">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/5">Cookie policy</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item" data-group="4">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/6">För medarbetare</a>
  </li>
  <li class="page_item" data-group="5">
    <a href="http://exampel.com/7">Information</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially set all page items to not display, `.page_item{display:none}`, and then on ready run this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var par = $(".current_page_item").parents('.page_item')
        elem = (par.length) ? par : $(".current_page_item") 

    elem.show().find(".page_item").show()       
});
```

Not sure if I should have deleted/edited my original answer or not, but I thought of a simpler solution afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This is for displaying current children and hide all other's children.
In this snippet, you can try it.
click on the main `li` or its children `li.page_item` - and all other's children will be hidden.

```js
$('li:not(.page_item)').on('click',function (){//This is for first goal    
  let ul = $(this).children('ul:first'); 
  showCurrentChildren(ul);  
});

$('li.page_item').on('click',function (){//This is for second goal
  let ul = $(this).parent(); 
  showCurrentChildren(ul);  
});


function showCurrentChildren(ul){
  if(ul.hasClass('children')){
    $('.children').hide();//Hide all
    ul.show();//Show current children
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="http://exampel.com/1">Example1</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item">
        <a href="http://exampel.com/2">Example2</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item">
        <a href="http://exampel.com/3">Example3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li>
    <a href="http://exampel.com/4">Example4</a>
    <ul class="children">
      <li class="page_item">
        <a href="http://exampel.com/5">Example5</a>
      </li>
      <li class="page_item">
        <a href="http://exampel.com/6">Example6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,none of the solution did work with JS ,i guess i cannot describe the problem very well.
I did solve the issue by css only:

```
.left_sidebar .children{
  display: none;
  margin-left: 15px;

}
.left_sidebar ul li.current_page_item .children{
  display: block;
}
li.page_item.page_item_has_children.current_page_ancestor.current_page_parent .children {
  display: block;
}
.left_sidebar li.current_page_ancestor .children{
display: block;
}
```